# Load joinedload results as a scalar list in SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: sqlalchemy

How to load a joinedload in this example as a scalar list of ids:

```
session.query(tables.Roles).options(joinedload(tables.Roles.permissions).load_only(tables.Permissions.id)).filter(tables.Roles.id == id).first()
```

So that the result:

```
{
     id:1,
     name:"admin",
     permissions: [1,3,6]
}
```

Insead of `permissions` being a set of objects:

```
{
     id:1,
     name:"admin",
     permissions: [
                     { id: 1 },
                     { id: 3 },
                     { id: 6 }
                  ]
}
```